# How do you specify a regex character range that will work in European languages other than English?

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode, internationalization

I'm working with Ruby's regex engine. I need to write a regex that does this

```
WIKI_WORD = /\b([a-z][\w_]+\.)?[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z]\w*\b/
```

but will also work in other European languages besides English. I don't think that the character range [a-z] will cover lowercase letters in German, etc.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Usually Ruby 1.9. I can require Ruby 1.9 in my gem if necessary.

Comment: As I understand it, Ruby 1.9 has far better Unicode support than 1.8<, so my guess is that Tim's suggestion should work with 1.9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
WIKI_WORD = /\b(\p{Ll}\w+\.)?\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+\p{Lu}\w*\b/u
```

should work in Ruby 1.9. `\p{Lu}` and `\p{Ll}` are shorthands for uppercase and lowercase Unicode letters. (`\w` already includes the underscore)

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627767/rubys-stringgsub-unicode-and-non-word-characters) - you might need to run Ruby in UTF-8 mode for this to work, and possibly your script must be encoded in UTF-8, too.

Comment: What does \p and /u at the end do?

Comment: `\p` is a shorthand for [Unicode character property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop). `/u` is the Unicode modifier. It appears to be necessary to tell Ruby that it should interpret the regex in Unicode mode, but I'm not really sure about this, and I haven't found a conclusive piece of documentation on this yet. Most stuff I have is still for Ruby 1.8.

Comment: According to Programming Ruby 1.9 when constructing a Regexp from a string "the encoding of the string determines the encoding of the regular expression". So unless otherwise specified the string argument will be encoded using `Encoding.default_external`, which defaults to UTF-8. I think.

Comment: StackOverflow could  and probably should use something more like your WɪᴋɪWᴏʀᴅ pattern. I noticed [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127725/how-could-i-catch-an-unicode-non-character-warning/5128605#5128605) that they weren’t using `\p{Lu}` properly, because it missed my Greek identifier. (Yes, I know it may be in bad taste; I was just play around.)

Answer (score 1):

James Grey wrote a [series of articles](http://blog.grayproductions.net/categories/character_encodings) on working with Unicode, UTF-8 and Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2. They're important reading.

With Ruby 1.8.7, we could add:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -kU
require 'jcode'
```

and get partial UTF-8 support.

With 1.9.2 you can use:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

as the second line of your source file and that will tell Ruby to default to UTF-8. Grey's recommendation is we do that with all source we write from now on.

That will not affect external encoding when reading/writing text, only the encoding of the source code.

Ruby 1.9.2 doesn't extend the usual `\w`, `\W` and `\s` character classes to handle UTF-8 or Unicode. As the other comments and answers said, only the POSIX and Unicode character-sets in regex do that.