# Regex to match first word in sentence

Tags: regex, text-segmentation

I am looking for a regex that matches first word in a sentence excluding punctuation and white space. For example: "This" in "This is a sentence." and "First" in "First, I would like to say \"Hello!\""

This doesn't work:

```
"""([A-Z].*?(?=^[A-Za-z]))""".r
```

Comment: What flavour of regex is this?

Comment: Can the words have numbers in them?

Comment: `([a-z]+)`, case-insensitive, should be sufficient for "non-tricky" English .. however, it will fail for non-latin characters quickly - so update to [use Unicode character classes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5005122/166390) as appropriate! Note that this assumes an NFA regex (like Ruby :D) which will "match the first thing it can", but that works in favor here as there is no need to anchor or otherwise complex look-arounds.

Comment: Start of a sentence or start of a string, like in your examples? What is about e.g. "It's not a good idea!" or "Fürchterlichéß Beispiel." (just an example!)?

Answer (score 14):

```
(?:^|(?:[.!?]\s))(\w+)
```

Will match the first word in every sentence.

http://rubular.com/r/rJtPbvUEwx

Comment: "123 This doesnt work" as it will return "123" instead of "This"

Comment: That is because that is the first word. Like OP had asked. If you want it to match the first dictionary word then you should be looking someplace other then regex.

Comment: Would you kindly explain what everything before (\w+) does, please?

Answer (score 5):

This is an old thread but people might need this like I did.
None of the above works if your sentence starts with one or more spaces.
I did this to get the first (non empty) word in the sentence :

```
(?<=^[\s"']*)(\w+)
```

Explanation:

`(?<=^[\s"']*)` positive lookbehind in order to look for the start of the string, followed by zero or more spaces or punctuation characters (you can add more between the brackets), but do not include it in the match.
`(\w+)` the actual match of the word, which will be returned

The following words in the sentence are not matched as they do not satisfy the lookbehind.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex: `^[^\s]+` or `^[^ ]+`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex: `^\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`.

The first word can be found at a captured group.

Answer (score 2):

```
[a-z]+
```

This should be enough as it will get the first a-z characters (assuming case-insensitive).

In case it doesn't work, you could try `[a-z]+\b`, or even `^[a-z]\b`, but the last one assumes that the string starts with the word.